# I can't launch my localhost websocket server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

I am trying to create a localhost websocket server with node 16.13 and I don't know why but I nothing seems to work. I can't launch my index.js with node index.js, I receive this error message -> `Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)`

Also this message in the browser `Access to script at 'file:///.../server/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.`

In my html file I've used `<script type="module" src="./server/index.js"></script>`

````js
(index.js file) 
import WebSocket from 'ws';
    
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080});

const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
    console.log("We're connected")

    ws.send("Hey, how is going?");
});

ws.on("connection", ws => {
    console.log("New client Connected");

    ws.on("message", data => {
        console.log(`Client has sent Us: ${data}`);
    });
    
});

ws.on("close", () => {
    console.log("client has disconnected");
});```
````

Comment: I don't know that you can open a Server WebSocket from HTML, but even if you could, it isn't right. You need to open your Server WebSocket from a persistent node.js process.

Answer (score 0):

You are importing your module with ESM syntax and nodejs only support CommonJs

Change

```
import WebSocket from 'ws';
```

For:

```
const ws = required('ws')
```